# Is it safe to run regsvr32.exe multiple times?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I need to register msdia100.dll if the computer that I'm working on doesn't have it registered. Instead of looking into registry, I just run `regsvr32 msdia100.dll`. Is it safe way to do? I mean, is it OK to run regsvr32.exe multiple time?

Or, is there any way to check if some dll is registered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's perfectly safe.

To check if something's already registered you'd have to write a program to check for the correct registry entry. This isn't a trivial task, especially when there could be several versions of the dll registered.

Answer (score 0):

**2019 Update**

Not sure if this wasn't possible in 2011, but now it's possible whether the DLL is registered by opening regedit and going to *Edit > Find* and searching by the DLL's name. If it's registered, after some time you'll be shown a folder named with GUID of this DLL which contains some extra information and physical location of the installed DLL.